# vba code to click pull down menu

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

There is pull down menu as shown below
[image]

And the html code is
[image]

I am thinking to use IE.document.getElementByID(), While it do not have id

--Edit--
According @David, I searched online i may employed getelementsByTagName

Therefore i employed the following code

```
Set tag = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For each tags in tag
   If tags.href = "/bsp/pages/plus/rptPlusSegment.jsp" then
       tags.Click
   End If
Next
```

Comment: well then you won't be able to use `.getElementById()` method. That leaves you the option of doing brute-force iteration `getElementsByTagName` or `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: hi @david, as the pull down list have many items. while it cannot distinguish the element by tag a or class.

Comment: Right. You will have to use a combination of the tag or class and some other properties like the inner text

Comment: I still cannot figure out the answer. Any tips? @DavidZemens

Comment: That looks like the right approach, can you share more of your code? Also, if possible can you share the URL?